# Error 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on MySQL Ubuntu Server

Tags: mysql, virtualbox

les comento que cree una maquina virtual con ubuntu server, en la cual instale mysql para pruebas y phpmyadmin. Desde la maquina virtual puedo acceder por terminal a mysql con el usuario y contraseña con root o con el otro user que cree.
Con:

**mysql -u root -p**

Y esa maquina virtual tiene una ip por la cual yo me intento identificar desde otra maquina en la red con el siguiente comando:

**mysql -u root -h 192.168.0.190 -p -P 3306**

Pero obtengo el siguiente error:

**ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.0.190:3306' (61)**

*He realizado muchas opciones de lo que plantean en el foro, como modificar el **bind-addres**, o #nombrarlo para que no tome el valor, tambien he abierto el puerto en cuestion **3306** y no logro dar conexion desde la red*

Puedo acceder remotamente a phpmyadmin desde la ip/phpmyadmin sin problema y loguear con root o cualquier otro usuario. Pero si intento por consola no es posible la conexion.

***Alguien tendra alguna idea de que puede estar fallando?
Adjunto imagenes de los archivos modificados incluso del puerto.***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Prueba quitando el `#` en la línea `#bind-address = 0.0.0.0` y reinicia el mysqld... eso creo que pondrá al mysql a la escucha en todas las ips que tenga la máquina virtual y no solo el 127.0.0.1 que no es accesible desde fuera

Comment: Hola @masterguru Al hacer ese cambio tampoco me permite ingresar por red local desde la terminal, y tambien note que me dejo de dar acceso por phpmyadmin. Asi que ahi esta perjudicandome tambien.

Comment: En tu respuesta sí que aplicas lo que dije en mi comentario (poner 0.0.0.0) y dices que funciona, aunque no entiendo que en tu captura ponia `#bind-address = 0.0.0.0` para el archivo **/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysql.cnf** y en cambio en tu respuesta pones que ponia otra cosa y una línea nueva con mysqlx-bind-address.  ¿no era el mismo archivo que mostrabas en la captura?

Comment: Hola masterguru, si me sirvio en parte, ya que no era el archivo correcto que debia modificar, era otro archivo, por eso puse la ruta original, y esta tarde adjunto una captura de pantalla como se ve el archivo original, los archivos que estaba modificando no tenian el bind-address correcto, y al descomentarlo me daban errores.

Comment: los archivos que estaba intentando modificar eran mysql.cnf y my.cnf y ambos daban error, hasta que encontre mysqld.cnf con una D al final y este si tenia el parametro correcto de bind-addres, al pasarlo a 0.0.0.0 me permitio acceder desde la red y por consola. Gracias masterguru.

Comment: vale, ahora si, entendido todo :-)   Me alegro que ya lo tengas arreglado. Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Lo solucione modificando el siguiente archivo:

**/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf**

**Las lineas que modifique fueron:**

```
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
mysqlx-bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

**Las modifique por**

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
mysqlx-bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

De esta manera ya pude acceder desde otro equipo en la misma red, pero imagino que si fuera un servidor tambien permitiria el acceso remoto. Espero que les sirva.

Adjunto imagen del archivo como se deberia ver:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]