# Conexion base de datos MYSQL cliente - servidor

Tags: java, mysql, mysqlconnector

Estoy tratando de generar una conexión de una aplicación web desarrollada en JAVA 8 mediante el mysql-conector-java-5.1.23, la base de datos se encuentra en un servidor diferente de donde se va a desplegar la aplicación web por lo que intento hacer pruebas de conexión con el netbeans y desde la aplicacion compilada, sin embargo no es posible siempre me arroja el mismo error    **com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failur**
He revisado algunas publicaciones anteriores y estas me indican varios pasos a seguir de los cuales puedo decir que hice todo y nada como, por ejemplo

**Verifíquelos y pruébelos con ping.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Actualice el DNS o use la dirección IP en la URL de JDBC en su lugar.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Verifíquelo en base a my.cnfMySQL DB.**
**Verifique si mysqld se inicia sin el --skip-networking option.**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Inicie la base de datos.**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Reinicie la base de datos y corrija su código en consecuencia para que cierre las conexiones en finally.**

**Deshabilite el firewall y/o configure el firewall/proxy para permitir/reenviar el puerto.**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**configure la conexion**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

** Otorge todos lo privilegio al usuario**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y despues de todo esto sigue arrojando el mismo error, he echo un telnet para verificar los puertos y este es el resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿alguien sabe que puede estar pasando?

Comment: Estamos hablando de una **conexión remota**. ¿Otorgaste permiso, en el servidor donde está la BD, para permitir conexiones remotas? Si la IP del cliente es fija, será fácil autorizar esa IP o rangos de IP, si es variable, o si son varios clientes con IPs distintas (imaginemos una App distribuida para quien sea), lo mejor será crear un tunel y usar llaves privadas / públicas para conectar. Lo digo por la seguridad, pues no deberías permitir todas las conexiones remotas sin control. Revisa [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/51886/29967) para más detalles.

Comment: Según lo que has puesto, el puerto está correctamente abierto y tu telnet te lo confirma bien (eso si lo has hecho desde la máquina que intenta acceder al servidor mysql remoto,... si lo has hecho desde otra parte quizás el problema sea de firewall que ha bloqueado la IP donde corre el java por lo que sea). Lo único que se me ocurre es un tema de permisos (GRANT)  del usuario/password que intentes usar, que no estan permitidos por algun motivo. ¿Cómo creastes dicho usuario/password?

Comment: la conexiona al servidor de base de datos siempre sera de una misma ip, sin embargo en el momento de crear el usuario y la nueva conexion en el my.ini configure la linea bind-address    = 0.0.0.0 para que permita la conexion de diferentes ip

Comment: Tambien el telnet lo estoy haciendo desde la maquina en donde es la apliacacion desplegada y en mi maquina ambas funcionan

Comment: ¿has intentado conectarte a dicha base de datos con tu usuario y contraseña desde un phpmyadmin o parecidos que esten corriendo en el propio servidor mysql?  Es para estar seguros que existe y tiene permisos sobre dicha base de datos correctamente.  Si es que si, ¿lo has probado remotamente con alguna otra herramienta visual?  Quizas este restringido a la ip del localhost y no externas.

Comment: intente conectarme desde el mysql workbench desde el otro servidor y no lo permite

Comment: Quizás es lo que estoy sugiriendo desde el principio, y cuando creastes el usuario se le asignaron permisos así:  `grant all privileges on base_de_datos.* to nombre_usuario@localhost identified by 'la_contraseña';`  en lugar de así: `grant all privileges on base_de_datos.* to nombre_usuario@'%' identified by 'la_contraseña';`  para permitir ese usuario desde cualquier ip

Comment: con esos privilegios se creo el usuario

Comment: Bueno, pues ya me he quedado sin ideas :-)  Mira si [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/563213/263200) te ayuda, aunque no se como se configura el mysql en windows o si hay archivos parecidos (eso es en linux)

Comment: Otra cosa, siendo que tu versión de MySQL es la 8, ¿por qué no usas la versión 8 del conector? [El MR dice que es altamente recomendable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/) usar la versión 8 del conector, tanto en MySQL 8, o incluso si tuvieras la versión 5.7 de MySQL: *"MySQL Connector/J 8.0 is highly recommended for use with MySQL Server 8.0 and 5.7. Please upgrade to MySQL Connector/J 8.0"*. Y, por favor, pon el código como texto en las preguntas, no como capturas de imagen.

Comment: ya he modificado el conector y sigue sin funcionar

Comment: Prueba con `ALTER USER 'el_usuario'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'la_contraseña';`  para intentar reestablecer los permisos de ese usuario, a ver si cuela

Comment: Y en [este enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50570592/mysql-8-remote-access) dicen alguna cosa más sobre como crear los usuarios remotos, pero para mysql 8... no sabemos que version usas tu

Comment: Y según leo por ahi, el nombre del parámetro ha cambiado en la 8... ya no es `bind-address` sino `bind_address` segun [este manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/ipv6-remote-connections.html)

Comment: Parece que en algunos casos no funciona ni `bind-address` ni `bind_address` en la versión 8 y hay que crear un nuevo usario `'root'@'%'` y luego otorgarle privilegios de acceso con `GRANT`, revisa las respuestas a [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50570592/5587982) para más detalles.

Comment: De todos modos, aunque funcione, la seguridad de la base de datos quedará expuesta. [Revisa este apartado del MR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-connection-ssh.html), pues desde la versión 8 es mucho más fácil conectar mediante un túnel.